# Zero look back time in autosys

Tags: autosys

I just want to know what `0` represents in "look back" clause of autosys.

For example:

```
s(job_name,0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0-01/reference/ae-job-information-language/jil-job-definitions/condition-attribute-define-starting-conditions-for-a-job.html#concept.dita_786915b26a4b3d5a37f3cedc0c9adf3d406804ea_LookBackDependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0 declares that a predecessor condition is only valid if it is newer than the jobs own state.

Example: a predecessor runs at 12:00 and its successor runs at 12:01. a time condition tells the successor to run again at 1:00 however 12:01 is more recent than 12:00 and lookback 0 does not validate. If the predecessor runs again at 1:30 then 1:30 is more recent than 12:01 and lookback 0 will then validate and start the second job.